# iOS Swift ScrollView, UITableView, scroll area

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

[image]

I have a view like attached image, the top part are images & labels, middle part are 3 tabs, the bottom part is table view. I want that when swiping up, even when users touch the table view to swipe, the whole view move up, not just table view content. And when scrolling up and navigation bar reaches the 3 tabs, these 3 tabs are kept on top, and the tableview will keep scrolling it's content. Like below image. How can I achieve this? [image]

Comment: And when scrolling up and navigation bar reaches the middle part, these 3 tabs are kept on top. I don't understand. show me a picture of how you want it to be.

Comment: check this https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView

Comment: Have you implemented code for this? Or just asking before start implementing this.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this yet, that's why I asked

Comment: @elk_cloner: plz check the second attached image, that's what I want it to be

Comment: @MikeAlter: thanks, but I want to do this myself, not using 3rd party library, so I can control the code

Comment: did you try it ?if yes show us some code.

Comment: as I said, I have no idea how to do this. I already have code for this view controller but only allow table view to scroll

Comment: Dear Hoang Trung, you can achieve this by maintaining auto layout related outlet properties in your view controller. Just put all your UI objects in a view and get reference of auto layout properties in your controller. Then according to your requirement when ever user performs required actions just change auto layout constants in code.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnarjunBanoth, but this is a very general answer, I still have no idea what constraint I need

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the following code. I did some stroyboard setting for convenience. Ask me if you got any question.
[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var darkGrayView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var grayView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var redViewTopConstrain: NSLayoutConstraint! 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        darkGrayView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        grayView.backgroundColor = .gray
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Let's try"
        return cell!
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.01
    }
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if  redViewTopConstrain.constant != -60{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.redViewTopConstrain.constant = -60
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** 
Source code of the Storyboard（right click the Stroyboard file -> open in -> source code）:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="12120" systemVersion="16F73" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="643-Rb-BwK">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="12088"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="Test1" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="grouped" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="18" sectionFooterHeight="18" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="e2z-6e-7xi">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="184" width="375" height="483"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="groupTableViewBackgroundColor"/>
                                <prototypes>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" reuseIdentifier="cell" id="dUE-aw-Mel">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="55.5" width="375" height="44"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="dUE-aw-Mel" id="ogF-HR-Apy">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </prototypes>
                            </tableView>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6Ey-Bf-14y">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="124" width="375" height="60"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </view>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PrH-WT-w4c">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="375" height="60"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="60" id="p1E-cJ-38m"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Ey-Bf-14y" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="PrH-WT-w4c" secondAttribute="height" id="2W6-Id-tzd"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Ey-Bf-14y" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="PrH-WT-w4c" secondAttribute="bottom" id="O0X-Kb-jHD"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Ey-Bf-14y" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerX" id="SIG-nu-NdA"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="e2z-6e-7xi" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerX" id="b8G-6I-bN9"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="e2z-6e-7xi" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="width" id="cTJ-6L-ngk"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="PrH-WT-w4c" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="mvJ-P9-whS"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="PrH-WT-w4c" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerX" id="nFF-iq-SDG"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Ey-Bf-14y" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="width" id="ojH-MK-ZEU"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="wfy-db-euE" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="e2z-6e-7xi" secondAttribute="bottom" id="qJ5-Lp-moa"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="PrH-WT-w4c" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="width" id="rF1-Tx-GkV"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="e2z-6e-7xi" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Ey-Bf-14y" secondAttribute="bottom" id="w8E-1f-Qbp"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="hAA-f7-INh"/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="darkGrayView" destination="PrH-WT-w4c" id="qyF-Mv-VrY"/>
                        <outlet property="grayView" destination="6Ey-Bf-14y" id="Xh9-V9-Ug9"/>
                        <outlet property="redViewTopConstrain" destination="mvJ-P9-whS" id="AAY-Lx-heP"/>
                        <outlet property="tableView" destination="e2z-6e-7xi" id="K3I-Th-fqz"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1056.8" y="122.78860569715144"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="RVN-Qw-5As">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="643-Rb-BwK" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="f1e-bq-GKK">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="VrF-oh-acv"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="rQX-j1-VaE" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="117.59999999999999" y="776.76161919040487"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: oh yes, this is exactly what I want. Would u plz share storyboard file, so I can see constraints you set?

Comment: @HoangTrung My chrome browser crashed  every time I edit my answer(even paste, copy). Actually, I wrote a SnapKit version without Storyboard. Don't know how to update, because it's too long to put it here as comment.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I ran it, but this is not what I want :(